# How to pass Children component state to Parent component state in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, for design I am using Ant design.

In the parent component `App` in `App.js` there are two buttons: `Show Child's First Button` and `Show Child's Second Button`.
There is also a `Child` component imported from `Child.js`.

Now what I am trying to do: when I click `Show Child's Second Button` I have to show `customizedDataRefundAmount` div and I have to hide
`customizedDataTotalAmount` div. To achieve this I need to pass child's state to the parent component, so please help me to resolve this issue.

This is my code App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from 'antd';
import Child from "./Child/Child";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./App.css";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="primary">Show Child's First Button</Button>
      <Button type="danger" style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Show Child's Second Button</Button>
      <Child></Child>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is Child.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd"
import "./Child.css";

const Child = () => {
    const [showTotalAmount, setShowTotalAmount] = useState(true)

    const [hideRefundAmount, setHideRefundAmount] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
            {showTotalAmount &&
            <div className="customizedDataTotalAmount">
                <h3 className="dueAmount">
                    Total Due Amount
                </h3>
                <h3 className="dueAmountCost">$150</h3>
            </div>
}
            {hideRefundAmount &&
            <div className="customizedDataRefundAmount" style={{marginLeft: "90px"}}>
                <h3 className="refundAmount">
                    Total Refund Amount
                </h3>
                <h3 className="refundAmountCost">$100</h3>
            </div>
}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

Comment: without knowing the details of the complete project, it would be easiest to just add the buttons to the child in the section they are needed. No other logic needed than what is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply handle the amount visibility flag from the parent component and then pass your boolean value on the buttons by `onClick`. In the child component, I used the ternary operator to show the correct amount according your description. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-children-component-state-to-parent-component-state-in-react-using-hooks-cdrvg?file=/src/Child/Child.js)

Parent

```
export default function App() {
  const [showTotalAmount, setShowTotalAmount] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setShowTotalAmount(true)}>
        Show Child's First Button
      </Button>
      <Button
        type="danger"
        onClick={() => setShowTotalAmount(false)}
        style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
      >
        Show Child's Second Button
      </Button>
      <Child showTotalAmount={showTotalAmount} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child

```
import React from "react";
import "./Child.css";

const Child = (props) => {
  const { showTotalAmount } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {showTotalAmount ? (
        <div className="customizedDataTotalAmount">
          <h3 className="dueAmount">Total Due Amount</h3>
          <h3 className="dueAmountCost">$150</h3>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          className="customizedDataRefundAmount"
          style={{ marginLeft: "90px" }}
        >
          <h3 className="refundAmount">Total Refund Amount</h3>
          <h3 className="refundAmountCost">$100</h3>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```